# Validate if one of two form fields is filled out typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Was unsure of how to do this - basically i want to require one of the two fields in this object for "VideoID" and "VideoId_MS". I know how to do this in javascript when hooked into HTML but not here. Any tips appreciated. Thanks

```
export default {
    name: "video",
    type: "document",
    title: "Video",
    fields: [
        {
            name: "title",
            type: "string",
            title: "Title",
        },
        {
            name: "videoId",
            type: "string",
            title: "Video Id (Brightcove). ",
            description:
                "Copy and paste this ID from the Brightcove media dashboard. ",
        },
        {
            name: "videoId_MS",
            type: "string",
            title: "Video Id (MindStamp)",
            description: "Copy and paste this ID from the MindStamp media dashboard.",
        },
    ],
```

Comment: That's JavaScript also. Create a javascript script to validate what you need.